# Взаимодействие Erlang и C#

Tags: c#, erlang

Захотел поближе познакомиться с Erlang. Возникли вопросы. Например:

1. Можно ли связать Erlang и C#, если
       сервер написан на первом, клиентская
       часть на втором ?
2. Можете подкинуть
           ссылок, на учебники, статьи, по
           которым вам понравилось изучать этот
           язык ?

Вопрос не совсем по теме, подскажите, какой более менее востребованный на данный момент объектно ориентированный язык мне стоит изучить ?

Comment: @DreamChild, на счет SOAP завтра посмотрю, спасибо за наводку. Я не имел в виду, что мне нужен тот самый единственный язык, вы уж тут слишком драматизируете. Всего лишь язык для расширения своего кругозора, который мне возможно пригодится сейчас или в будущем и который не связан с веб программированием.

Comment: @Sier речь о том, что когда вы задаете подобные (чего уж там, холиварные) вопросы, то вряд ли имеет смысл ожидать объективных мнений. Кто-то вам скажет "учи Java", кто-то ответит "фтопку Java, вот Python - это круто", еще один кто-то возразит, что будущее за C# и так далее.

Comment: @DreamChild, извините, не подумал, да и забыл, что возможен холивар по этому поводу.

Comment: @Sier, для простого обмена данными для своих клиента и сервера (т.е. если Вы свободны в выборе протокола обмена) рекомендую посмотреть на [JSON](http://json.org/).

Comment: оффтоп. Говорят, SOAP сейчас редко используют. Так ли это? Неужто только в майкрософт стеке ввиду wcf он наиболее распространен?

По-своему небольшому опыту видел использование soap как раз только в wcf сервисах.

Comment: Очень крутая книга по Erlang
http://learnyousomeerlang.com/

Answer (score 1):

Используйте bert. Реализовано на F# Filbert - https://github.com/fsprojects/Filbert.
Из C# хорошо и легко используется.

Answer (score 0):

1. Можно. Просто нужно договориться о протоколе. Идеально зайдет xmlrpc. Куча реализаций и там и там.
2. Основная книга, по которой я начинал http://learnyousomeerlang.com/content

   http://xmlrpc.scripting.com xmlrpc 
   https://github.com/etnt/xmlrpc реализация на эрланге 
   http://xml-rpc.net/ реализация на .net